# Python RegEx multiple LInes

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am stuck.  I am trying to get rid of the tag and the whitespace between the tag using a regex.

```
b="<NAME> 
   content here 
   more content
</NAME>
"
result = re.sub("<NAME.*?NAME>", "", b)
```

If 'b' is all on one line it work.  It removes everything between the name tags.  But I need it to work with multiple lines as well.

Comment: Dot never matches newline unless you [turn on single-line mode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S).

Comment: Don't use regex to parse XML.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is not correct. You can use the following regex:

```
In [7]: print(re.sub(r'\s*</?NAME>\s*', '', b))
content here 
   more content
```

or:

```
In [8]: print(re.sub(r'\s*</?NAME>\s*\n', '', b))
   content here 
   more content
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe I did not explain myself very good. But what I am trying to accomplish is to get rid of everything between the tags and remove the tags also.  The In 7 does remove the spaces and the name tags but it leaves the other characters inbetween.

Comment: This is what I have so far. I just need to combine so it is only one. re.sub(r'(.+\s*</?NAME>\s*,'',b);
The above removes everything inside the name tag and the </name> tag. 
I made another regex to remove the first name tag 
re.sub(r'<name>\s*','',b). How do i combine them?

Comment: @user3525290 So can you just add your expected output to your question?

Comment: I figured it out. The expected outcome should have been "Left over text". from b="<name> junk in here to remove </name> Left over text". What I wanted to do was remove the name tags and everything inbetween. What I came up with thanks to this help was.     re.sub(r'^<name>.?</?name>') however this will only work if <name is at the beginning of the file.